# Sorting multidimensional number array in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, numbers

I have issues sorting an multidimensional array.

The array looks like:

```
$array = array(
  array("token" => array(100, 240, 348, 23, 17),
  array("token" => array(293, 28, 283, 2, 28),
  array("token" => array(842, 23, 72, 98, 114)
);
```

Now I want to sort them by "column". That means, the first column of numbers (100, 293, 842) must be sorted, then the second column (but keeping the first column as it is! It may happen that the columns have the same number with multiple rows) and so on.

Actually I tried this to do with usort(), but this will work only when sorting the first column:

```
function do_sort($a, $b) {
  $tok_a = $a["token"];
  $tok_b = $b["token"];

  if ($tok_a[0] <= $tok_b[0])
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}

usort($array, "do_sort");
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Can you add the expected output in your question?

Comment: An expected output would be indeed good. Otherwise i would recommend reading the documentation of `array_multisort` http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.array-multisort.php -- maybe it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's possible solution:

1. get rid of 'token', i.e., make 2D array
2. swap columns and rows (*transpose* array)
3. sort each column
4. swap back columns and rows (get initial structure)
5. put 'token' back

Code:

```
function array_transpose(array $array) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ( $array as $rowNum => $row ) {
        foreach ( $row as $colNum => $value ) {
            $result[$colNum][$rowNum] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$array = array(
  array("token" => array(100, 240, 348, 23, 17)),
  array("token" => array(293, 28, 283, 2, 28)),
  array("token" => array(842, 23, 72, 98, 114)),
);

// get rid of 'token'
foreach ( $array as &$item ) {
    $item = $item['token'];
}
unset($item);

// swap columns and rows
$array = array_transpose($array);

// sort columns
foreach ( $array as &$item ) {
    sort($item);
}
unset($item);

// swap back columns and rows
$array = array_transpose($array);

// put 'token' back
foreach ( $array as &$item ) {
    $item = array('token' => $item);
}
unset($item);

// display results
foreach ( $array as $row ) {
    foreach ( $row['token'] as $value ) {
        printf('%-7d', $value);
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
100    23     72     2      17     
293    28     283    23     28     
842    240    348    98     114
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you are after. I've made some assumptions here (such as `$array` is *really* an array, has at least one sub-array, all sub-arrays have `token` as the key, and all sub-arrays have the same number of elements).

```
<?php

$array = array(
  array("token" => array(100, 240, 348, 23, 17)),
  array("token" => array(293, 28, 283, 2, 28)),
  array("token" => array(842, 23, 72, 98, 114)),
);

$count_outer = count($array);
$count_inner = count($array[0]['token']);

for ($i=0; $i < $count_inner; $i++) {
    $temp_arr = array();

    for ($j=0; $j < $count_outer; $j++) {
        $temp_arr[] = $array[$j]['token'][$i];
    }
    sort($temp_arr);

    for ($j=0; $j < $count_outer; $j++) {
        $array[$j]['token'][$i] = $temp_arr[$j];
    }
}

foreach ($array as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Output:

> array(1) { ["token"]=> array(5) {
>   [0]=> int(100) [1]=> int(23) [2]=>
>   int(72) [3]=> int(2) [4]=> int(17) } }
>   array(1) { ["token"]=> array(5) {
>   [0]=> int(293) [1]=> int(28) [2]=>
>   int(283) [3]=> int(23) [4]=> int(28) }
>   } array(1) { ["token"]=> array(5) {
>   [0]=> int(842) [1]=> int(240) [2]=>
>   int(348) [3]=> int(98) [4]=> int(114)
>   } }

Comment: The good news are that we understood author the same way and that we have the same result (while solutions are different).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just

```
foreach ($array as &$item) {
  sort($item['token']);
}
```

Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. If we look at each `$item['token']` as at "row", sorting is needed by "columns", not by "rows". At least that's how I and @Aether understood the problem.